# Give examples in $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ of a set $A ⊂ \Bbb R^2$ which is open, not closed, not bounded.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Somebody please needs to explain to me what I have to do. I have been struggling all day to understand the concepts but I have absolutely no idea what to do. I know what $\Bbb R^2$ is and I know the definition of $\|\cdot\|_2$ but I still don't know what a subset of this set should be, which criteria it should fulfill to be a subset of $(\Bbb R^2, \|\cdot\|_2)$ and then how do I tackle it.

I would really appreciate some understanding. It was taught extremely vaguely in our class and I have been trying all day to find literature or texts which can really help me but they don't, so if someone could explain the concept to me and help me out I would be very glad.

Thanks

Comment: What about $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2|y>0\}$?

Answer (score 2):

$$A= \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$$

- Complement of a closed set, thus open.
- Not closed, because $(1/n,1/n)\to (0,0)$, or because $\{(0,0)\}$ is not open.
- Not bounded is evident.

Other examples (without explanation):

- $A=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus F$ where $F$ is any finite subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$
- The complement of any line in the plane.